Problem with Laravel + Vue.js - problems with synchronisation between products from OLX API and WooCommerce REST API
Please, help me, I am having trouble making the synchronisation between the fetched OLX adverts and the fetched WooCommerce REST API products from a website via the automattic PHP package. What we need to do, is to fetch the olx adverts, fetch the woocommerce products, and compare them. Whatever is being fetched as olx adverts listing, should be put in the woocommerce product listing, so the olx adverts list should be used as a reference, so that these lists will be the same. Here is the OLX API documentation - https://developer.olx.bg/api/doc
And here is the automattic WooCommerce REST API documentation: https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce
I have a frontend component - Adverts.vue, which partly looks like this:
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary m-3" @click="syncWithWebsite">Синхронизирай с продуктите в уебсайта</button>

    <script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    selectedAdvert: null,
    adverts: [], // Array to store user adverts for the current page
    allAdverts: [], // Array to store the complete list of user adverts
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: 1,
    loading: true,
    editing: false,
  };
},

  computed: {
    totalPages() {
      return Math.ceil(this.adverts.length / this.itemsPerPage);
    },

    paginatedAdverts() {
      const start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.itemsPerPage;
      const end = start + this.itemsPerPage;
      return this.adverts.slice(start, end);
    },
  },
enter code here

  mounted() {
    console.log('Mounted lifecycle hook executed.');
    // Check if the access token is available in the cookie
    const accessToken = this.getCookie('olx_access_token');

    if (!accessToken) {
      console.log('Access token not available.');
    } else {
      console.log('Access token available. Fetching all user adverts.');
      // Access token is available, fetch all user adverts
      this.fetchAllUserAdverts(accessToken);
    }
  },


methods: {
 async syncWithWebsite() {
    try {
      // Fetch the user's adverts data
      const accessToken = this.getCookie('olx_access_token');
      await this.fetchAllUserAdverts(accessToken);

      // Send the adverts data to the Laravel controller
      const response = await axios.post('/syncWithWooCommerce', {
        adverts: this.allAdverts,
      });
      
      if (response.data.success) {
        console.log('Synchronization successful!');
        // Optionally, you can show a success message to the user
      } else {
        console.error('Synchronization failed:', response.data.message);
        // Optionally, you can show an error message to the user
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during synchronization:', error);
      // Optionally, you can show an error message to the user
    }
  },

async fetchAllUserAdverts(accessToken) {
    this.loading = true;
    try {
      // Fetch all user adverts and store them in allAdverts
      this.allAdverts = await this.fetchUserAdverts(accessToken, 0, []);

      // Update the adverts array with the paginated data from allAdverts
      this.updatePaginatedAdverts();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching user adverts:', error);
    } finally {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  },



    fetchUserAdverts(accessToken, offset, allAdverts) {
      const apiUrl = `/olx/show-adverts?access_token=${accessToken}&offset=${offset}`;
      return axios
        .get(apiUrl, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            Version: '2.0',
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('API Response:', response.data);
          const currentAdverts = response.data.data;

          // Append the current adverts to the existing array
          allAdverts.push(...currentAdverts);

          // Check if there are more pages to fetch
          const nextPageExists = currentAdverts.length === this.itemsPerPage;
          if (nextPageExists) {
            // Fetch the next page recursively
            return this.fetchUserAdverts(accessToken, offset + this.itemsPerPage, allAdverts);
          } else {
            // Return all adverts when no more pages are left
            return allAdverts;
          }
        });
    },
},

Here is part of the OlxController.php, with the method for the syncWithWooCommerce. I've created three jobs for trying to ease the process of the synchronisation. I also am putting the code for the fetching of the user adverts of olx, and the fetching of the woocommerce products:
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Olx;
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Services\OlxApiClient;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
    use App\Jobs\CreateWooCommerceProductJob;
    use App\Jobs\UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob;
    use App\Jobs\SynchronizeProductsJob;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Products\ProductsController;
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client as WooCommerceClient;
    
    class OlxController extends Controller{
    
        protected $olxApiClient;
        protected $woocommerce;
    
        public function __construct(OlxApiClient $olxApiClient, WooCommerceClient $woocommerce)
        {
            $this->olxApiClient = $olxApiClient;
            $this->woocommerce = $woocommerce;
        }
     
    
    
        public function __sleep()
        {
            return ['olxApiClient', 'woocommerce'];
        }
    
        public function __wakeup()
        {
            $this->olxApiClient = app()->make(OlxApiClient::class);
            $this->woocommerce = app()->make(WooCommerceClient::class);
        }
    
        public function syncWithWooCommerce(Request $request)
        {
            \Log::info('Starting synchronization job dispatch');
            // Extract the adverts data from the request
            $olxAdverts = $request->input('adverts', []);
        
            // Dispatch the job with the received adverts data and the WooCommerce client instance
            SynchronizeProductsJob::dispatch($olxAdverts, $this->woocommerce);
            \Log::info('Synchronization job dispatched');
        
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Synchronization job has been dispatched.']);
            \Log::info('Synchronization job dispatched');
    
        }
    
   protected function getWooCommerceProducts()
    {
        // Fetch products from WooCommerce using the ProductsController logic
        return app(\App\Http\Controllers\Products\ProductsController::class)->fetchProducts();
    }
      public function getUserAdverts(Request $request)
{
    /*
   $accessToken = $request->query('access_token');
   */
   $accessToken = $request->cookie('olx_access_token');

    // Log the request and access token for debugging
    /*
    \Log::info('Request received for getUserAdverts:', [
        'request' => $request->all(),
        'access_token' => $accessToken,
    ]);
*/
    // Decode the URL-encoded access token
    $decodedAccessToken = urldecode($accessToken);


    // Check if the access token is present
    if (!$decodedAccessToken) {
        // Log the missing access token for debugging
        \Log::error('Access token not found in the request.');

        // Return an error response
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Access token not found'], 400);
    }

    // Make a request to get user adverts
   $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $decodedAccessToken,
        'Version' => '2.0',
    ])->get('https://www.olx.bg/api/partner/adverts', [
        'offset' => $request->input('offset', 0),
        'limit' => $request->input('limit', 10), // Adjust as needed
    ]);

    // Check if the response is successful
    if ($response->successful()) {
        // Decode the JSON response
        $adverts = $response->json()['data']; // Update this line according to the OLX API response structure

        // Return the adverts data as JSON response
        return response()->json(['data' => $adverts]);
    } else {
        // Log the unsuccessful response for debugging
        \Log::error('Error fetching user adverts:', [
            'status' => $response->status(),
            'headers' => $response->headers(),
            'body' => $response->body(),
            'access_token' => $decodedAccessToken, // Log the access token for additional information
        ]);

        // Return a more informative error response
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Error fetching user adverts', 'status' => $response->status()]);
    }
}

As a queue worker in Laravel, I am using redis. Here is how my SynchronizeProductsJob.php looks:
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\Services\OlxApiClient;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use App\Jobs\CreateWooCommerceProductJob;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Jobs\UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client as WooCommerceClient;

class SynchronizeProductsJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $olxAdverts;
    protected $woocommerceClient;

    public function __construct(array $olxAdverts, WooCommerceClient $woocommerceClient)
    {
        $this->olxAdverts = $olxAdverts;
        $this->woocommerceClient = $woocommerceClient;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        \Log::info('Starting synchronization process');
    
        try {
            // Fetch all products from WooCommerce
            $wooCommerceProducts = $this->getAllWooCommerceProducts($woocommerceClient);
    
            // Compare OLX adverts with WooCommerce products and find missing products
            $missingProducts = $this->findMissingProducts($this->olxAdverts, $wooCommerceProducts);
    
            // Update WooCommerce product status
            $this->updateWooCommerceProductStatus($this->olxAdverts, $wooCommerceProducts, $woocommerceClient);
    
            // Upload missing products to WooCommerce
            $this->uploadMissingProductsToWooCommerce($missingProducts, $woocommerceClient);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error('Error during synchronization:', [
                'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                'file' => $e->getFile(),
                'line' => $e->getLine(),
                'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
            ]);
        }
    
        \Log::info('Synchronization process completed');
    }
    protected function getAllOlxAdverts($limit = 100, $offset = 0)
    {
        $allAdverts = [];
    
        $response = $this->olxApiClient->getUserAdverts($this->request, $offset, $limit);
        $adverts = json_decode($response->getContent(), true)['data'];
    
        $allAdverts = array_merge($allAdverts, $adverts);
    
        // If the number of adverts fetched is equal to the limit, recursively fetch the next batch
        if (count($adverts) === $limit) {
            $allAdverts = array_merge($allAdverts, $this->getAllOlxAdverts($this->request, $limit, $offset + $limit));
        }
    
        return $allAdverts;
    }

    protected function getAllWooCommerceProducts()
    {
        // Moved the logic from OlxController::getAllWooCommerceProducts() here
        // Use $this->woocommerceClient to interact with the WooCommerce API
        
        $products = [];
        $page = 1;
    
        do {
            $response = $this->woocommerceClient->get('products', [
                'page' => $page,
                'per_page' => 100, // Adjust as needed
            ]);
    
            $newProducts = $response->json();
    
            if (empty($newProducts)) {
                break;
            }
    
            $products = array_merge($products, $newProducts);
            $page++;
        } while (true);
    
        return $products;
    }

protected function findMissingProducts($olxAdverts, $wooCommerceProducts)
    {
        // Moved the logic from OlxController::findMissingProducts() here

        $missingProducts = [];

        // Log OLX advert titles
      //  \Log::info('OLX advert titles:', array_column($olxAdverts, 'title'));

        // Log WooCommerce product names
        //\Log::info('WooCommerce product names:', array_column($wooCommerceProducts, 'name'));

        // Iterate over OLX adverts
        foreach ($olxAdverts as $olxAdvert) {
            // Check if the OLX advert title exists in WooCommerce product names
            if (!in_array($olxAdvert['title'], array_column($wooCommerceProducts, 'name'))) {
                // If the OLX advert title does not exist in WooCommerce products, add it to missing products
                $missingProducts[] = $olxAdvert;
            }
        }

        // Log the missing products
      //  \Log::info('Missing products:', $missingProducts);

        return $missingProducts;
    }

    protected function updateWooCommerceProductStatus($olxAdverts, $wooCommerceProducts, $woocommerceClient)
    {
        // Moved the logic from OlxController::updateWooCommerceProductStatus() here
        // Use $this->woocommerceClient to interact with the WooCommerce API
        foreach ($wooCommerceProducts as $product) {
            $status = in_array($product['name'], array_column($olxAdverts, 'title'))
                ? 'publish'
                : 'draft';
    
    //                    \Log::info('Dispatching UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob for product ID:', $product['id']);
    
           // UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob::dispatch($product['id'], $status, $this->woocommerce);
           UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob::dispatch($product['id'], $status, $woocommerceClient); 
                //              \Log::info('UpdateWooCommerceProductStatusJob dispatched for product ID:', $product['id']);
        }
    }

    protected function uploadMissingProductsToWooCommerce($missingProducts, $woocommerceClient)
    {
        // Moved the logic from OlxController::uploadMissingProductsToWooCommerce() here
        // Use $this->woocommerceClient to interact with the WooCommerce API
        foreach ($missingProducts as $missingProduct) {
            // Log before dispatching the job
            // \Log::info('Dispatching CreateWooCommerceProductJob for product:', $missingProduct);
    
            // CreateWooCommerceProductJob::dispatch($missingProduct, $this->woocommerce);
            CreateWooCommerceProductJob::dispatch($missingProduct, $woocommerceClient);
            // Log after dispatching the job
           // \Log::info('CreateWooCommerceProductJob dispatched for product:', $missingProduct);
        }

    }
}

The problem is that I am not receiving any errors right now, I am not able to compare the olx adverts with the woocommerce products, and even though the SynchronizeProductsJob gets dispatched, nothing really happens:
[2024-05-14 15:42:15][6ohQhGSCexdL2urDbqogtAKjlbC3l5jQ] Processing: App\Jobs\SynchronizeProductsJob
[2024-05-14 15:42:15][6ohQhGSCexdL2urDbqogtAKjlbC3l5jQ] Processed:  App\Jobs\SynchronizeProductsJob
I think we are not actually fetching the woocommerce products in the SynchronizeProductsJob.php, and therefore we are not able to actually compare them with the olx adverts. I believe I am wrong way with my code with the SynchronizeProductsJob.php, or I need to do some other things, in order to make the synchronisation work successfully?
